# Is there a way in Instagram's API to get the URL to a new post from a specific user? I'd like to integrate it with a Reddit bot

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, reddit

The Owl City subreddit (/r/OWLCITY) is running into a unique problem: Whenever Adam Young posts something new to Instagram (@owlcityofficial), there's an influx of new Reddit posts saying that Adam posted something new.  I suggested (and if I can get it off the ground, hope to do so with the approval of the subreddit's moderators) to create a bot that automatically creates a new post whenever Adam posts something to Instagram, as a sort of "master thread."  All discussion about the post could be had there, with all others being subject to deletion.

This appears to be easier said than done.  Looking briefly at Reddit's API's this appears to be possible.  But on Instagram's end, that's another story.  It appears Instagram deprecated and shut down their first API last year, and I can't find any information on whether the two APIs still available support something like this.  I would prefer to use the Display API, as I doubt I qualify to use the Graph API.  Furthermore, I can't find any useful information on the Instagram API.  Also, almost any search for what I'm trying to do shows a plethora of results of how to do it with the OLD API, and limiting the results to the last year doesn't bring up anything useful.

Is there a way to do what I want to do?  Keep in mind I'm relatively new to programming, so any help with this would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Python with Selenium to get the Channel Page and get the first entry. Compare it with and if it is newer, scrape it. No API needed, if you not want to dig to deep into API references.
Try search for Instagram Basic Display API.
Please specify what kind of programming Language you have experience.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).